# why is not my navigation bar sticky after scrolled down to some portion of the screen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tailwind-css

i want to make my nav sticky when it is scrolled down to 200 px height but it is not being sticky even when scrolled all the way down. I want to make scroll sticky something like this as shown in the following link    https://preview.colorlib.com/#cohost

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'


function Nav() {
    const [stickyShow,setStickyShow]=useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', handle)
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', handle);
      }
    }, [])
    const handle=()=>{
        if(window.scrollY > 200){
            setStickyShow(true);
        }
        else {
            setStickyShow(false)
        }
    }
    
    const item=[
        {h1:'Home'},
        {h1:'New'},
        {h1:'Blog'},
        {h1:'About us'},
    ]
  return (
    <div>
        <div className={`${stickyShow? 'sticky':'relative'}`}>
        <div className='px-2 py-2 bg-slate-400'>
            <ul className='flex justify-between'>
            {item.map((val,i)=>{
                return <li key={i}>
                    {val.h1}
                </li>
            })}
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div className='h-[800px] bg-red-300'>
x   
        </div>
    </div>
    
  )
}   

export default Nav
```

is my calling the function handle not correct?

Comment: Why are you removing the scroll event, that's for life of the page if you expect it to return from its sticky state. The use of your eventlistener scroll is correct but I'm vanilla here so can't say if handle is being called. I can't confirm the rest of the code, don't know react.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify at least one of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` for sticky positioning to work, [w3s](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp)

Adding a `top: 0` should work for you.

```js
 <div className={`${stickyShow? 'sticky top-0':'relative'}`}>
```